Popover content misaligned inside safe area
I have a .popover with some content. I want it to ignore the safe area and function just as it would normally. This is what it should look like:

However, the content has a gap for the safe are and overflows on the other side.
HStack {
    Text("")
        .popover(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(.green)
                .frame(width: 150)
                .padding(10)
                .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
        }
    Spacer()
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.all)

(I'm using an iPhone with safe area in landscape here)

If I add .ignoresSafeArea(.all) to the RoundedRectange it ignores the "arrow inset", which looks just as broken:
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(.green)
  //...
  .ignoresSafeArea(.all) // <- also doesn't fix it


Is there a way to fix this?

If you're not able to find a better workaround, you could consider using a custom popover instead. Then you can position it and also style it any way you like.

Are you sure you want to do this? On iPhone 15 Pro Max for example, the dynamic island hides a large part of the popover.

@Sweeper Yes, I'm aware of that. If I only show it in landscape right it's not an issue though (but still fragile ofc).

Through some experiments, it seems like the rectangle seems to be shifted to the right, by half of the safe area width.
You can read the safe area using a GeometryReader, and give a negative x offset:
GeometryReader { geo in

    // GeometryReader changes how the views are laid out - this VStack is to vertically centre the HStack
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Text("")
                .popover(isPresented: .constant(true), arrowEdge: .top) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(.green)
                        .frame(width: 150)
                        .padding(100)
                        .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
                        .offset(x: -geo.safeAreaInsets.leading / 2)
                }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
    }

    // this should be on the view that is inside of the GeometryReader, not on the GeometryReader itself
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
}


Thanks :) It works in this case, but sadly doesn’t if the Text("") view is sometimes inside and sometimes outside the safe area as the issue is only happening inside the safe area.

@fer0n Oh the text can move? From your comment I'd assumed that the Text just acts as an static anchor to show the popover. In any case, I found another way of doing this. Does the edited answer work for you?

I don't see a difference to .ignoresSafeArea(.all), am I missing something? I'm starting to think it's just not possible without making a custom popover, but the GeometryReaderversion was technically correct, if you want to change it back I'll accept it

@fer0n My bad! I just realised I was messing around with this on portrait mode... I have rolled back.
